# Checkmarx Client DOM XSS Violation in ReachJS

Tags: xss, javascript

I have this message from Checkmarx:

> The application's = embeds untrusted data in the generated output with location, at line 19 of `****.js`. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

It is shown below code:

```
    const url = (window.location.href || '');
    const newHref = url.replace('parameter=12', '');
    if (newHref !== url) {
      window.location.href = newHref;
    }
```

I used `sanitizeHtml` and `JSON.stringify` `const url = window.location.href || ''`, but neither helped correct the problem. How is it possible to correct this type of error?

below didn't work either

`window.location.href = new URL('', window.location.href).href.replace('parameter=12', '')`